# mxGraph - Non editable mode

Tags: javascript, php, mxgraph

Actually I am storing the mxGrpah XML nodes in to the database, during the retrieval getting all the nodes from database, consolidating and binding to the graph.

**Scenario:**
At a time multiple users can view/edit the diagram.If it's happened lot of conflicts will be occurred. So to avoid conflicts one user can edit the diagram at a time, for other users is just locked i.e. other users can view the existing diagram, system should not allow to edit. For that I've to set other users should not allow to change the diagram. *Is there any possibility to set the graph is non editable?*

[image: mxGrpah editor]

Comment: I don't really understand what you would like to achieve is make the nodes of the graph non-editable?

Comment: @NickAth, I've edited the question.Please check.

Comment: mxGraph.setEnabled(false);  https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.setEnabled

Comment: @David, Yes I referred and implemented already. Working fine for me. Thanks David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I referred the answer from [jgraph forum](https://forum.jgraph.com/accept_answer/5545/index.html) and it's working fine.

```
var editorUiRefresh = EditorUi.prototype.refresh;
EditorUi.prototype.refresh = function()
{
  editorUiRefresh.apply(this, arguments);

  this.editor.graph.setEnabled(false);
};
```